# The fragment data of the corresponding tab of viewpager need to be loaded only when the tab is clicked

Tags: android, android-fragments, tabs

I am having a viewpager and having 3 tabs in it. All the three tabs are having their fragments. What I noticed that each fragment data is getting loaded at the first time when I am setting adapter to viewpager.

What I need is to load the fragment data of the corresponding tab only when the particular tab is getting clicked.

I have noticed one more issue in it. Like when the activity started in which I am having viewPager, then the data of the first tab's fragment get loaded at the same time the data of the second tab's fragment also get loaded and that is shown when I click on that tab.
Same way when I click on Second Tab, third Tab's Fragment date get loaded.

So what I need is that the data of the fragment should be loaded only when I click on the particular tab.

Thank you so much in advance..

Answer (score 2):

You should use the `ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(0)` to only load the currently displayed content.

Comment: Can you please guide me how can I use LocalBroadcastReciever here to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Its the View-pager behaviour that it loads one page left/right to current page even if you have specified `setOfflinePageLimit(0)`.

To load each fragment on click on tab, you should use `LocalBroadcastReciever`.

Comment: Can you please guide me how can I use LocalBroadcastReciever here to achieve this ?

Comment: Hii, I am having one issue with GridView and Adapters. 
I am having a gridView and the data in the grid view is getting loaded from a server. 
Each Row is having one icon, when we will click on that icon that particular row should be hidden and some new layout should be shown there. 

How can I Achieve this, can you please help me here.